# Mellin transform of rescaled delta distributions

Tags: analytic-number-theory, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, mellin-transform

There's something about the Mellin transform I don't get, so hopefully someone can tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Let's define the Mellin transform of $f(t)$ as $\mathcal{M}\{f(t)\}(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) t^{s-1} dt$.

First, let $\delta(t-n)$ be the Dirac delta distribution that spikes at $t=n$. According to [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html), the Mellin transform of such a distribution is

- $\mathcal{M}\{\delta(t-n)\}(s) = n^{s-1}$

Second, multiple references, such as [this book](http://dsp-book.narod.ru/HFTSP/8579ch18.pdf), list the "rescaling property" of the Mellin transform as

$\mathcal{M}\{f(at)\}(s) = a^{-s} \mathcal{M}\{f(t)\}(s)$

But these two things don't seem to play nicely together.

For instance, let $g(t) = \delta(t-n)$ for some n. Then $g(at) = \delta(at-n) = \delta(t-\tfrac{n}{a})$. But:

- $\mathcal{M}\{\delta(t-\tfrac{n}{a})\} = (\tfrac{n}{a})^{s-1}$
- $\mathcal{M}\{g(at)\} = a^{-s} \mathcal{M}\{g(t)\} = a^{-s} n^{s-1}$

and it's clear that $(\tfrac{n}{a})^{s-1} \neq a^{-s} n^{s-1}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true that $\delta(at-n) = \delta(t-\frac{n}{a})$.

With the usual interpretation of what rescaling of a distribution should mean,
$$
\delta(ct) = \frac{1}{|c|}\delta(t).
$$
See for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) for more on the properties of $\delta$.

Comment: Aha, thank you! That explains it.

Comment: So how does this work for $\delta(at-n)$? The proper identity is $\tfrac{1}{|a|} \delta(t-\tfrac{n}{a})$, right?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Yes, that looks right.